# Trouble with making fetch array contain variable

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

i am trying to loop a database routine, but i have problems making an fetch array contain a variable.g

```
${"db" . $currentTime . "11"} = ${"data" . $currentTime . "1"}[${$currentTLower . "11"}];
```

`$currentTime` contains 'A'

`$currentTLower` contains 'a'

So line of code would look like this:

```
$dbA11 = $dataA1[a11];
```

But, it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Index should be 'a11' but not `$a11` as in your code

```
$currentTime = 'A';
$currentTLower ='a';
$dataA1['a11'] = 'value';

${"db" . $currentTime . "11"} = ${"data" . $currentTime . "1"}[$currentTLower . "11"];

echo $dbA11; // value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$currentTime = "A";
$currentTLower = "A1";
$A111 = "Test";
$dataA1[$A111] = "This is content";
${"db".$currentTime."11"} = ${"data".$currentTime . "1"}[${$currentTLower . "11"}];
echo ${"db".$currentTime."11"};

// IT will print : This is content
?>
```